# Ошибка с сохранение в базе данных

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Привет!Я создавал приложение и мне понадобилось добавить в бд данные.
Вот мой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PlusRecepies : Form
    {
        public PlusRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlusToFlp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductPlus.Text;
        }

        public void AddRecipe()
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe
            {
                Instructions = RecepiePRText.Text,
                Name = NameRecipe.Text,
                Prop_Time = Convert.ToDouble(PropTime.Text)
            };

            context.Recipe.Add(recipe);
            context.SaveChanges;
        }

        private void AddRecepieToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

И вот такую ошибку я получил,хоть на примере все работало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  WindowsFormsApp1    C:\Users\user\Desktop\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\PlusRecepies.cs 38  Active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SaveChanges` - это метод. Так что `context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Ошибки нету теперь)))))

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov выдели как правильный ответ